# Я не могу подключиться с БД MySQL с Android приложения

Tags: java, android, mysql, connection

Мне нужно разработать приложение, которое будет select и insert данные на сервер.
Приложение должно иметь минимальный уровень API типа 19, чтобы работало на большинстве устройств.

Я пробовал работать с jdbc драйвером как в этом видео https://youtu.be/ryMj8xnZkSQ, но приложение просто выключается, даже не смотря на блок try catch.

```
private class Send extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String records= "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            textView.setText("Wait");
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jbdc:mysql://192.168.0.103:3306/auto_to_db", "Admin", "rotokan123rot");
                if(connection==null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "We have a problem, Huston", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                    {
                        String quary = "select fio from users";
                        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                        stmt.executeUpdate(quary);
                        msg="Success";
                }
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                msg="Wrong";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                msg="Wrong";
            }
            return msg;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg)
        {
            textView.setText(msg);
        }

    }
```

В build.gradle(madole:app) прописал jdbc драйвер и "разрешил работу с тырнетом"(android.permission internet). В общем подробно следовал гайду.

Сервер локальный на моей машине, приложение на эмуляторе, брендмауэр вкл выкл - бесполезно.

Пробовал ещё https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TM1Suk7sLbc https://youtu.be/H-SE1m_A-SA с участием php. Но я так и не смог понять куда надо загружать php скрипты.

Если учёные всего мира разработали способ решения моей проблемы, а вы его знаете - поделитесь пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

> Но я так и не смог понять куда надо загружать php скрипты.

PHP загружаешь на твой сервер.
Для запуска просто обращаешься к нему как к обычной веб странице.

```
                    String phpUri = "https://www.my_site.ru/my_script.php";
                    Uri address = Uri.parse(phpUri);
                    Intent openlink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
                    startActivity(openlink);
```

Comment: Спасибо что ответили.

А как размещать что-то на сервере?

Comment: Ну ты, программер, даёшь )))
Записываешь файл в папку сайта да и всё.

Comment: Да я ж начинающий. Многого не знаю. 
Вот вчера до меня только допёрло "что я делаю не так".